# Sync with live: false

Tags: data-synchronization, pouchdb

I have a running copy of the Getting Started Guide.  It syncs perfectly with a CouchDB server (at couchappy.com).  So far so good.

I need the sync to happen only with a user action (ie. a user hits a button).  So I added a button to the markup and wired the click event to the same "sync()" function provided in the Getting Started Guide.  Lastly, I changed the two "live" options from "true" to "false".

Whether or not I change values on the client, server or nowhere, when I click the button, it calls the sync function and I get an error for both the replicate.to and replicate.from.  I must be missing a basic concept in PouchDB.  Can someone help me understand how to get replication working not "live"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your error is, but most likely you need to enable CORS. Check [this tutorial](http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html), search "CORS".

If that doesn't work, then post your error here along with the version of PouchDB that you're using.

Also, `live` is `false` by default, so you don't need to mention it at all. :)

Comment: Thank you in advance for your help.  I ran the debugger and looked at the return values from db.replicate.to and db.replicate.from.  They both call the syncError method (defined in the example) but in looking through the return values, the only error I can find is a "ThrowTypeError" but no additional information about it. 
I also double checked all the CORS settings and they match the information provided in the link you sent over.  When I change the Live option to true, it syncs live perfectly both to and from the server.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Or are you testing in Node.js?